# Detecting duplicate values

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table, it's structure is,

```
companies - table
id
name
url
logo
```

From this table i want to check whether name already exists, url exists, logo exists before inserting.  name, url and logo should be unique. I can check like,

```
SELECT * FROM companies WHERE name='$name' OR url='$url' OR logo='$logo'
```

and count the number of records. From the above query, is there anyway i can detect which field is duplicate? So, that i can display that field as duplicate in showing errors in views.

Thanks

Comment: Side note: Don't `SELECT *` and count the returned rows - use `SELECT COUNT(*)` instead.

Comment: @Stobor On the other hand, actually counting the returned rows is exactly what the OP needs, because they can also check the column values in the process and see which are duplicates.

Comment: @lc. Good call - on reflection there are at most 3 rows returned in this case (due to the uniqueness constraint), and the data can be used, so there is no significant penalty for returning everything...

Answer (score 2):

You can create a unique key which will cause your insert to fail - this avoids needing two queries:

```
ALTER TABLE `companies` ADD UNIQUE (
 `url`, 
 `name`,
 `logo` 
);
```

Answer (score 0):

yes you can.. as you must have placed 'id' as the primary key for the table.

you can do certain things as adding **unique key with `logo`** and then **indexing `name`
, `url`, `logo` as unique.**

and try this

```
SELECT `id` FROM companies WHERE name='$name' AND url='$url' AND logo='$logo'
```

and show error for duplication if you encounter any such value.

Answer (score 0):

this is your select query.

```
SELECT name,url,logo FROM companies WHERE name='$name' OR url='$url' OR logo='$logo';
```

then loop the results

```
$num_of_records=0;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{

if($name==$row['name'])
{
  echo  . " name -> " . $row['name'] ." duplicated ";
  echo "<br>";
}
else if($url==$row['url']) 
{
  echo  . " url -> " . $row['url'] ." duplicated ";
  echo "<br>";
}
else if($logo==$row['logo'])
{
  echo  . " logo -> " . $row['logo'] ." duplicated ";
  echo "<br>";
}
 $num_of_records++;
}
```

echo "number of records -> ".$num_of_records;